# Title for option element

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a field in my table named `product`. I create a `select` in view file by this code

```
echo $this->Form->input('product'));
```

I also set a variable from Controller to view:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $prods[$product['Product']['price']] = $product['Product']['name'];
}
$this->set('products', $prods);
```

CakePHP generates `value` and `text` portion for `<option>` element when it finds `$products` array in the view file. I need to set `title` attributes for the options `CakePHP` generates. Is there any way? As I use `SecurityComponent` I cannot print all the hundreds of options by `foreach`. So, my question is, **How to make CakePHP to create `title` attribute for option element as the way they create `value` attribute?**

Comment: Loop and create an array of a `$options` array with title and required attribute & than give it to select element as options parameter.

Comment: I tried this `$i = 0;
                foreach($products as $product){
                    $prods[$product['Product']['price']] = $product['Product']['name'];
                    $optionsProducts[$i++] = array('title' => $product['Product']['price'], 'required');
                } $this->set('optionsP', $optionsProducts);` then in the view `echo $this->Form->input('product', $optionsP);` but not working.

Comment: You need to give as `echo $this->Form->input('product', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$optionsP));`

Comment: It's not working for me :(

Comment: What issue you facing using that way ?